# C++ Template implementation file extension convention?

Tags: c++, templates, coding-style

Is there a convention for what file extension is used for template class implementation? **.tpp .template .hpp **

Comment: there is no convention, but if you choose a strategy, do it consistently preferably within the module or better yet, the whole project.

Comment: I've tried to extend about the dangerous parts regarding IDE's and automated build systems. Have a look.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> *"Is there a convention for what file extension is used for template class implementation?"*

No there isn't really a standard convention established for these file extensions AFAIK.

There's a number of file extensions commonly used though, like

- `.icc`
- `.inl`
- `.tcc` (which seems at least to be used by my GCC 4.8.1 standard libraries  implementation)
- `...`

It doesn't really matter that much, because you'll need to be explicit about it with the `#include "MyImpl.tcc"`, `#include "MyImpl.tpp"` statement in the template header file anyway.

You could use for instance `.tci` (**t**emplate **c**lass **i**mplementation, one I've invented creatively on the fly here ;-) )

One important point is, you should use a consistent naming strategy over all of your projects involved to the solution (This would make it even easier to set up you IDE preferences for syntax highlighting).

---

The only ***no go*** extensions IMHO are `.cc`, `.cpp`, `.cxx` and `.c`, which would confuse most of the automated build systems and IDE's currently around. The build system will assume these files need to be to build and linked as additional objects, and fail because of these either can't be build standalone, or ending up with multiple symbol definitions in linkage.

Comment: Sometimes i'm using `.impl.hpp` or `.tpl.hpp`, as it automatically gives syntax highlighting, and it's not supposed to be automatically compiled. Would it be considered as a no go by most people ?

Answer (score 9):

No.

A lot of projects don't care much and just throw everything in the `.hpp` file. I do this.

A lot of other projects (big header-only ones like Eigen and Boost) split inlined code, and template implementations into `.inl` (for inline) files.

I've never personally seen `.tpp`, but that doesn't mean there aren't projects that do it.

But there's no convention, no.

Comment: I'm using `.tpp` (so its kind of consistent with `hpp` and `cpp`) when shipping the code. While developing, I do not split templated headers.

Comment: Boost mostly uses `.ipp`.

Answer (score 1):

The following at least are recognised by VSCode as C++ implementation files (non-exhaustive):

```
.ixx
.inl
.tpp
.ipp
.inc
...
```

VSCode doesn't seem to like `.tcc` and `.icc`.

I like `ipp` because it brings the "i of implementation". Boost authors apparently like it as well. But these are just my two cents.

#### Update 07.01.2024

It seems that currently from all the above the clangd extension only supports `.inc` which is recognised not as a header but source file by vscode. While the implementation file is technically a header file, this could still help the implementation fall in line with other `.cpp` implementation files so I'm inclined to say that it would be most idiomatic to use `.inc` from now on since it's also supported by clangd.