# Easier way to deal with templatized classes in C++ Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

To avoid compiler issues with .cpp and .h files in VS I always have to:

1. Seperate the template class into .h and .cpp files
2. Protect the .h from multiple inclusion with #ifndef
3. include the .cpp file in the .h file AFTER the class definition
4. include the .h file in the class implementation file and the application file
5. REMOVE the template class .cpp file from project (but don't delete) it, then add as an existing item to edit again.

My issue is with step 5. Is there a less clunky way of going about working with templatized classes than having to remove the .cpp file  every time? I typically combine the .cpp and .h files into .hpp files, but wondered if Visual Studio has a more elegant way of working with them seperately?

Comment: My advice is don't name it `.cpp` and never ever include a `.cpp` file. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264656/c-template-implementation-file-extension-convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264656/c-template-implementation-file-extension-convention)

Comment: Put all the template code in the header file. What exactly is the problem with this? It's certainly a lot simpler and less fragile than your method.

Comment: In certain situations I'm required to use .cpp and .h files, otherwise I would always put the template code in the header file

Comment: The normal pattern I've seen is to put template implementations in an `.hpp` file, which is included from the `.h`. Then you don't need step 5.  The `.hpp` also doesn't need to include the `.h` file.

Comment: @happysaint What situations are those?