# Separating C++ class into header(.h) and .cpp

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to implement Priority queue using Binary search tree.
I have the following header file:

```
template <class T>
class BSTQueue
{
private:
    struct Tree
    {
        T data;
        int priority;
        Tree* lt;
        Tree* rt;
        Tree(T Data, int Priority, Tree* left = nullptr, Tree* right = nullptr)
        {
            data = Data; priority = Priority; lt = left; rt = right;
        }
    };
    Tree* head = nullptr;
    Tree* insert(Tree* current, T data, int priority);
};
```

The problem is that function insert in .cpp generates errors. My .cpp file is the following:

```
#pragma once
#include "BSTQueue.h"

template<class T>
BSTQueue<T>::Tree* BSTQueue<T>::insert(Tree* current, T data, int priority)
{
    if (current == nullptr)
    {
        return new Tree(data, priority, nullptr, nullptr);
    }
    if (priority <= current->priority)
    {
        current->lt = insert(current->lt, data, priority);
    }
    else
    {
        current->rt = insert(current->rt, data, priority);
    }
    return current;
}
```

And the errors:

- Error    C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
- Error    C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
- Error    C2061   syntax error: identifier 'Tree'

I have no idea what should I do in order to fix them. Maybe someone knows what to do??

Comment: I've tried this variant, but it still doesn't work and gives same errors

Comment: The reason for closing this question does not seem correct. The problem is not that the function definition is in a separate file (yes, it should be in the header file, but that is an additional comment). The problem is that the "typename" keyword is needed: `template<class T> typename BSTQueue<T>::Tree* BSTQueue<T>::insert(BSTQueue<T>::Tree* current, T data, int priority`.

Comment: `#pragma once` shouldn't be in a source file. You also can't implement templates in source files. Also, you'll need to add `typename` before `BSTQueue<T>::Tree`

Comment: You should not implement your template in a cpp file. If you want to implement it separate file that is included in the header there are several choices: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264656/c-template-implementation-file-extension-convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264656/c-template-implementation-file-extension-convention)

Comment: Thanks, adding typename worked!