# How do I compile a template class if the .cc is included in the .h file?

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

For my assignment, my professor said we shouldn't #include "matrix.h" in our matrix.cc file because "matrix.cc" is already included in the .h file. However, when I try to compile, I am encountering an error message that says "'Matrix' does not name a type". Can you please suggest how I can resolve this issue and compile my program successfully?

```
//This code was included in the bottom of my header file 

#include "Matrix.cc"//to compile templates 
#endif

//in my .cc file  I compile a function like this.

template<class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int m, int n, T fv)
{

    rows = m;
    cols = n;        //m and n accepted

    data = new T [rows * cols];   //deallocate

    if (m > 0 && n > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                data[i * cols + j] = fv;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        m = 0;
        n = 0;
        fv=0;
    }
}
```

I keep getting errors stating

```
"error:  'Matrix' does not name a type
```

Comment: Is your professor really suggesting including a `.cc` file into a header? Ugh... Anyway, show a proper [mcve].

Comment: You should never include a `cc` in a `.h` is the other way around. Maybe you misunderstood him?

Comment: If possible I suggest you define (implement) as many functions as possible inline in the template class definition itself. If there are functions that are too large, create a "template source file" (commonly with an ending like `.tcc`) and include *after* the template class definition, e.g. `#include "Matrix.tcc"`. Then include the *header* file when the template class is needed

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz I know lol. But my professor said we should do it like that , for this specific assignment.

Comment: Please, add all the code, so we can see why, because as it is, we have no information about `Matrix.cc`, but my guess is that you are referencing that class before it is declared.

Comment: Probably you are using the name `Matrix` somewhere outside of the class template definition without template arguments. Whenever you use the name outside of class definition or member functions you need to write `Matrix<T>` or `Matrix<int>` or whatever.

Comment: You should really not name your implementation file `Matrix.cc` as this can be seen from some IDEs as a cpp source file instead of a template implementation.  See here for better choices: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264656/c-template-implementation-file-extension-convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264656/c-template-implementation-file-extension-convention)

Comment: And follow the advice I gave yesterday for the same question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75829494/how-to-fix-c-template-redefinition#comment133758871_75829494](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75829494/how-to-fix-c-template-redefinition#comment133758871_75829494) **matrix.h should include Matrix.cc but Matrix.cc should not include Matrix.h and no other file should include Matrix.cc and it should not be compiled directly.***

Comment: ***I am encountering an error message that says "'Matrix' does not name a type"*** I would expect that error if your project settings tried to build `Matrix.cc` as a source file separately. You can not compile this file separately. This is one reason to rename it to `Matrix.tcc` and make sure your build tools don't try to build it. It must only be included by `Matrix.h`  and nothing else and not built as part of your project, Makefile or on the compilers command line.